# Generate N-dimensional matrix of random floats in numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, random

To create N-dim matrix with numpy we can use:

```
matrix= np.random.randint(5, size=(5, 5))
```

Suppose I would like to get double values between 0 and 4 like 2.555 or 1.434 what function should i use?

Comment: Were the docs unclear for some reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `np.random.uniform` function as follows:

`np.random.uniform(0,4, size = (5,5))`

Sample output:

```
array([[1.37318128, 3.10722002, 2.39722365, 1.95412901, 2.29837145],
       [1.65331776, 3.37478222, 0.71290494, 0.64033497, 2.03541558],
       [2.65384027, 1.82204597, 3.88952334, 3.72478794, 1.41670979],
       [1.83850468, 1.96107175, 3.30916063, 2.33715428, 1.25788108],
       [0.9843734 , 3.8700671 , 0.63356675, 0.23514751, 1.96708274]])
```